# How can I take hundreds of smaller images and create one big tiled image?

Tags: images, script, automation, generator

I have 251 images that are 128x128 in size; I need to create one big image that includes them all tiled together.

The image will be 32128x32128 in size if all goes well (Paint.NET says it will be 3.8GB in size, fun times)

I need to do this systematically, with a tool or a script since I might have to do this a few times - it's very tiresome to do by hand. I have programming skills, so if the solution requires that, then no problem.

If your idea does not work for such a big image but would work with a part of the images, then I'd like to hear about it anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), a command-line image editor. Its **montage** command can help you tile your images together. For more info about `montage`:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/
- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php

Here's an example that tiles 100 PNG files in a folder together (10 images down, 10 images across).

```
montage *.png -geometry +0+0 -tile 10x10 all.png
```

where

**all.png** is the output file name

`-geometry +horizontalSpacing+verticalSpacing`
`-tile COLSxROWS`

Result:
[image]

Comment: Used ImageMagick and it did the trick. montage * -geometry +0+0 tiles.png Will take all the pictures in a folder and tile them up evenly with no spacing

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean photo mosaicing? A simple search of Google ended up here:

> http://www.engadget.com/2004/10/19/how-to-make-your-own-photo-mosaics/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few programs that will do this for you.  The smallest one that comes to mind is John's Background Switcher.