# How to pass a list of files to ImageMagick's montage?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a large number of tiles, with the following naming convention:

```
A-x-y.jpg
```

where

```
0<=x<=16 &
0<=y<=14
```

Now I know that [we can use the Montage tool](https://superuser.com/questions/313035/how-can-i-take-hundreds-of-smaller-images-and-create-one-big-tiled-image?lq=1) in ImageMagick, to merge them into one whole image.

Ideally I could have used the following command line:

```
montage *.jpg -geometry +0+0 -tile 17x15 all.jpg
```

but my files are such that A-0-0.jpg is directly above A-0-1.jpg, which is above A-0-2.jpg and A-1-0.jpg is to the right of A-0-0.jpg.

So when I use the above command the order is wrong. I have a text file with the correct order. Can I use the text file as an input to montage. If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 12):

In the newer versions of ImagMagick (i.e >v6.5.2-1)  [**@** operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read) can be used like this:

```
montage @list.txt -geometry +0+0 -tile 17x15 all.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It [looks](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) like montage does not support a "file with filenames" argument.</strike>

*Edit:* @Devdatta found the correct syntax (see also [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read)): `@filenames.txt`. So, the method below should only be necessary for very old versions of the ImageMagick tools.

---

But if you are using Linux or a Unix-like system, you can replace the filename argument(s) with the output of a command. This way, you can use your file with the ordered filenames:

```
montage `cat filenames.txt` -geometry +0+0 -tile 17x15 all.jpg
```

(Please note the backticks around the cat command.)

Line breaks between filenames in `filename.txt` do no harm to the command invocation. And you may even use wildcards in `filename.txt`, as command substitution precedes filename expansion.

Of course, you could also rename the source files beforehand to yield the order wanted.

Comment: Beware, this breaks if one of the file names contains whitespace of any sort.

Comment: PS: Under Windows Powershell, the following syntax could work (untested): `montage $(cat filenames.txt) -geometry +0+0 -tile 17x15 all.jpg`

Comment: This is also possible on POSIX. In fact, preferred over the backticks.