# How can I run mogrify over the 3 million JPG files?

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick, xargs, mogrify

I have 3 million JPG files stored in a Linux CentOS 6 server.

I want to change quality to %50 file size over 1 megabyte.
I wrote this command but got an "argument list too long" error:

```
$ find -type f -name "*..jpg" -size +1M | xargs mogrify -quality 50 *.jpg
bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long
```

How can I change the quality of millions of files?

Comment: Why do you add `*.jpg` to `xargs`? It will get the files from `find`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a list of files to ImageMagick's montage?](https://superuser.com/questions/620053/how-to-pass-a-list-of-files-to-imagemagicks-montage)

Answer (score 1):

When using `find` and `xargs`, you don't need to name the files for `xargs`. It will get the list of files from `find`:

```
find -print0 -type f -name '*.jpg' -size +1M | xargs -0 -n100 mogrify -quality 50
```

`-n100` will process the images by 100s. `-print0` and `-0` will make the pipe work even if the filenames contain whitespace.

You can also call `mogrify` directly from  find, ideally if it supports the `+` ending for `exec`:

```
find  -type f -name '*.jpg' -size +1M -exec mogrify -quality 50 {} +
```

Comment: This will still make the argument list too long in the first command, if all are passed to xargs in one. Also, you should pipe from `find` to `xargs` with `find ... -print0 | xargs -0`.

Comment: Well, luckily, `find` *can do it all*. :D Instead of ending the -exec command with `+`, it can also be terminated with `;`. This executes the command once per result. Don’t forget to escape `;`!

Comment: @DanielB: What is the advantage of `;` over `+` in this case?

Comment: It doesn’t result in a command line that’s too long. Although `find` might already work around that, who knows. It’s also suitable for commands that don’t accept batch input.

Comment: Well, although it may be a bit spammy, I discovered `xargs` and `find` are, in fact, smart enough to split the arguments collection automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` supports a `-n` argument to limit the amount of arguments passed to whatever it calls:

```
find -type f -name '*.jpg' -size +1M -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 mogrify -quality 50
```

This will launch mogrify once per image. As mogrify can only process one file at the time, this is the way to go.

Comment: `mogrify`'s documentation shows examples with `*.jpg`.

Comment: Ah, I blindly trusted the manpage: "SYNOPSIS
       mogrify [options] input-file" - indicating it only supports one.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker can you edit your answer then?

Answer (score 0):

A cross-platform solution with Python+convert: it will convert all PDF files of the current directory into PNG files (you can change to JPG if you prefer) multithreadedly.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import glob
import multiprocessing      

def convert_to_png(pdf_filepath):
    '''
    Convert PDF file to PNG file
    '''
    png_filepath = '{0}.png'.format(pdf_filepath[:-4])
    print('pdf_filepath: {0}'.format(pdf_filepath))
    print('png_filepath: {0}'.format(png_filepath))
    command = 'convert -background white -alpha off -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 -resize 800x {0} {1}'.format(pdf_filepath, png_filepath)
    print(command)
    os.system(command)

def main():
    pdf_filepaths = glob.iglob(os.path.join('.','*.pdf'))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(convert_to_png, pdf_filepaths)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()   
    print('done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

This requires  [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)  and  [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to be installed. Works on Linux/Mac OS X/Microsoft Windows.

If you prefer to add the filename on each image, you can replace the command in `convert_to_png()` by:

```
command = 'convert  -background white -alpha off -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 -annotate +50+50 {2} -resize 800x {0} {1}'.format(pdf_filepath, png_filepath, os.path.basename(pdf_filepath))
```

(See [-annotate](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate) documentation)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992092/136285), you could also do:

```
$ find -type f -name "*..jpg" -size +1M > my_jpeg.txt
$ mogrify -quality 50 @my_jpegs.txt
```